# How can I check if a TextField is focused in Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, textfield

I need to check if a textfield is focused, because if it's, then I can hide it.

Comment: did any of the answers solve your problem? Does the Focuslistener solution i suggested work?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [FocusListener](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/FocusListener.html) and add it to your TextField.
William Reeds soulution should also work, but it is also possible to switch to next TextField by calling method `next(boolean up)` in TextField or by pressing "tab" if you enable this option (`setFocusTraversal(boolean focusTraversal))`. In this cases the ClickListener won't work.
Try this and tell me if it works i am not sure...

Answer (score 2):

For a TextField in Libgdx to have focus it must be clicked. So a solution to this would be to add a ClickListener to the Text Field.

Here is an example of this.

```
    TextField text = new TextField("Text", skin);
    text.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        public void clicked(InputEvent e, float x, float y) {
            //perform some action once it is clicked.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just wish to check if an actor is focused or not you could use either `Stage#getKeyboardFocus()` or `Stage#getScrollFocus()` which will return the actor that is currently being focused for keyboard or scroll input. In this case the code might look something like this:

```
if (stage.getKeyboardFocus() == textField) {
    stage.unfocus(textField);
}
```

Comment: for me, `stage.getKeyboardFocus()` always returns null